# can not start sonarqube with jdbc url set from env variable

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I have a environment variable set as complete jdbc url for sonarqube

```
$echo $MYSQL_URL
jdbc:mysql://devdb3a100:6000/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
```

However, sonarqube does not start and in the logs I m seeing the issue with this jdbc url format.

```
> --> Wrapper Started as Daemon Launching a JVM... Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
> 
> 
> WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main:
> org.sonar.process.MessageException: Bad format of JDBC URL:
> ${env:MYSQL_URL} org.sonar.process.MessageException: Bad format of
> JDBC URL: ${env:MYSQL_URL} <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

What format it is complaining about?? The same jdbc if pasted directly in the sonar.properties file (instead of setting it via environment variable) sonarqube starts fine.

Please help. I am facing many issues specifically in the template'ing aspect of sonar.properties..

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem of using it in the sonar.properties file?

I have never heard that it was possible to use an env variable.

Regards.

Comment: Header / first few lines of sonar.properties mentions this. So it is possible to use env variable as value of a property. My use case restricts me to directly have a value in the sonar.properties file, as the value changes as per environment.